# how to get the RSS url in an html page?

Tags: html, rss, html-parsing, feed, atom-feed

Many html page has an url link to the RSS feed. If you have used google reader, you'll see if you add a site url (i.e: codemacro.com), it will automatically find the rss feed url which is codemacro.com/feed. So, my question is, how to find the rss url automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look for the `<link>`s in the `<head>` that give you the type of feed you are looking for. Most sites with feeds have links like:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/tech">
```

in their `<head>`. So you need to find those links with whatever programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The RSS Feed is generally linked via either `<link>` element, or with a normal `<a>` link whose extension is `.rss` The browser recognizes either of the two and displays proper options.